# Can I use one Try/Catch to encompass multiple items to be tested, and do something different in the catch depending on where the error occurred?

Tags: android, android-studio, try-catch

I want to convert a few strings into numeric values using parse. Can I put all strings being tested in the try and then output an error depending on where the error occurred?

```
try{
    intOne = Integer.parseInt(editTextOne.getText()...
    intTwo = Double.parseDouble(editTextTwo.getText()...
    intThree= Double.parseDouble(editTextThree.getText()...
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //if intOne threw an error display this text
    //if intTwo threw an error display this different text
    //if intThree threw an error display some more different text
}
```

I've looked around and all I really found was that I can test multiple lines and output an error with a toast in the catch, but I want the error to be specific to where the error occurred. End state is 'user enters letters in a numeric field, toast says specifically which edittext the invalid data occurred in.'

I know I could accomplish this with multiple try/catch, one for each line. I'm just trying to be more efficient/compact. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an int variable before the try block and assign it a different value before each line inside the try block and then check its final value in the catch block to determine where the exception was exactly occurred (see the following code)

```
int state = 1;
try{
    intOne = Integer.parseInt(editTextOne.getText()...
    state = 2;
    intTwo = Double.parseDouble(editTextTwo.getText()...
    state = 3;
    intThree= Double.parseDouble(editTextThree.getText()...
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    switch(state){
        case 1: //if intOne threw an error display this text
        break;
        case 2: //if intTwo threw an error display this different text
        break;
        case 3: //if intThree threw an error display some more different text
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply and answer acceptance. I was very tired and after I saw it worked I went straight to bed. But, this worked perfectly. Thanks!